# Changing build variant at run time

Tags: android, gradle

Good day everyone.
Is it possible to change the build variant at run time in android studio some how?

I have two server environments. One for debug build type and another for release.
The code itself relies on some strings and server addresses that are set when I pick my build variant. So when I pick debug for instance, the string uses out debug server address. The same for release.
But what if I want to be able to pick the environment during run time?
I wouldn't want to add both server urls to both build types just so I could be able to pick a different environment. This defeats the purpose of the build variant I believe.

So I was wondering if there is a way to change the build variant at run time, letting the gradle system sort things out?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gradle is a build system so without checking I'm assuming you wont be able to control runtime changes.
But from you description I don't see the need to change via gradle, allow the server strings to be changed after runtime via regular code

In my projects I always put a class named Endpoints that provided all the server urls.
It has a server_base string which is the base url to every url I tailor in the app.
The static constructor assigns a the server_base based on the build variant and if I need to change it I usually just add a secret menu in the app the allows me to change it.

There many approaches to what you are trying to achieve but I don't really think its good to rely on the build system to change server environment in runtime

I know this doesn't directly answer your question.

Comment: Hi Shai thanks for your reply. So in essence, you have all server addresses reside in the app and there's a "hidden" menu that has access to that information. I guess I can hide the menu when I pick release build type and unhide it in debug. Thanks. I'll try it this way. I simply wanted to refrain from holding all url options regardless of the build type... But I guess there's no real harm in doing that :)
Thanks!

Comment: You can remove plenty of the stuff you wish to hide with Proguard

Comment: Ohh so for instance, when I compile to release, proGuard will remove the classes that relate to this feature? Like the Constants class (with all the urls) and the menu itself? Something of this sort?

Comment: Yep. and then if someone can still access the secret menu the app will crash anyway